# handleSubmit triggered with invalid field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

So i'm using [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/pQj03w7Y6) example to try and build a simple form that validates synchronously.

This is my form:

```
const DatasetForm: React.StatelessComponent = (props: any) => {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
    console.log(props);

    return (<form onSubmit= { handleSubmit }>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <Field
                        name="firstName"
                        component= {renderField}
                        type="text"
                        label="First Name"
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>)
}
```

I'm using exactly the same `renderField` function and this is my validate function:

```
const validate = (values: IValues) => {
    let errors: IValues = {
        firstName: ''
    };
    if (!values.firstName) {
        errors.firstName = 'Required';
    }
    else if (values.firstName !== 'aaaaa') {
        errors.firstName = 'Must be aaaaa';
    }
    return errors;
}
```

The `handleSubmit` function is a simple `console.log` and is passed as a prop.

Now in the example the handleSubmit function doesn't seem to be called if a field is not valid. But in my code, it is definitely called every time i click the submit button. I've stared at both my and the example code for a long time without finding what may cause this difference. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Adding the export function:

```
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'simpleForm',
    validate
})(DatasetForm);
```

Comment: Didn't you forget to wrap your form in reduxForm?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in your custom `validate` function to your wrapped custom form `DatasetForm`. Like this:

```
const validate2 = (values) => {
  let errors = {};
  if (!values.firstName) {
    errors.firstName = 'Required';
  }
  else if (values.firstName !== 'aaaaa') {
    errors.firstName = 'Must be aaaaa';
  }
  console.log(errors);
  return errors;
}
```

---

```
const DatasetForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;

  return (<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <div>
      <div>
        <Field
          name="firstName"
          component={renderField}
          type="text"
          label="First Name"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>)
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'syncValidation',
  validate: validate2,
  warn
})(DatasetForm)
```

---

Check out this [working sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/7zn2r6nn31).